# Series Soln False error

Tags: variable-definitions

When I try to define my equation :

```
sys3 = {y'[x] == 2 y[x]/(1 + y[x]^2) - Exp[y[x]]/(1 + Exp[y[x]]), 
  y (0) == 1}
```

OR

```
sys3 = {y'[x] - 2 y[x]/(1 + y[x]^2) - Exp[y[x]]/(1 + Exp[y[x]]) == 0, 
  y (0) == 1}
```

I get back

```
{-(E^y[x]/(1 + E^y[x])) - (2 y[x])/(1 + y[x]^2) + 
   Derivative[1][y][x] == 0, False}
```

Why do I get this false error?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Try `Clear[y]`. Then define `sys3`.

Comment: What do you suppose `y(0)==1` will do?

Answer (score 1):

If both definitions of `sys3` are intended to be equivalent, you made a sign error.

```
xmax = 2;

sys31 = {y'[x] == 2 y[x]/(1 + y[x]^2) - Exp[y[x]]/(1 + Exp[y[x]]), 
  y [0] == 1} 

(*  {Derivative[1][y][x] == 
     -(E^y[x]/(1 + E^y[x])) + 
       (2*y[x])/(1 + y[x]^2), 
   y[0] == 1}  *)

soln1 = NDSolve[sys31, y, {x, 0, xmax}][[1]];

sys32 = {y'[x] - 2 y[x]/(1 + y[x]^2) - Exp[y[x]]/(1 + Exp[y[x]]) == 0, 
  y [0] == 1}

(*  {-(E^y[x]/(1 + E^y[x])) - 
       (2*y[x])/(1 + y[x]^2) + 
       Derivative[1][y][x] == 0, 
   y[0] == 1}  *)

soln2 = NDSolve[sys3, y, {x, 0, xmax}][[1]];

Plot[{y[x] /. soln1, y[x] /. soln2}, {x, 0, xmax}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"sys31", "sys32"}]
```

[image]